# Unable to set checkbox value to false when using disabled state in angular v4 with reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I will build the form with a form builder and include the following:

```
myCheckbox: [{ value: true, disabled: false }, ''],
```

Then I will try to patch the value, but this will only work if I am going from false to true, not from true to false:

```
 this.myForm.get('selectedItem').patchValue({
                selectedItem1: [{ value: false, disabled: false }, '']
            });
```

Am I missing something? Everything worked fine, until I used the recommended way for handling disabled state.

The checkbox looks like this in the html:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="selectedItem1" formControlName="selectedItem1">Week 1</label>
```

Comment: please remove angularjs tag and use angular instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should just be:

```
this.myForm.get('selectedItem').patchValue({
    myCheckbox: false
});
```